# Как отключить port security на коммутаторе Cisco?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, коммутатор

Столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу найти информацию про то, как отключить функцию `port security` на коммутаторе Cisco. Может кто сталкивался с этой проблемой.

Comment: Можно добавить подробностей?! Это статическая, динамическая или защита на основе привязки(sticky)? В такой формулировке вопроса - ответ командой **no**, как и все в Cisco IOS отменяется

Comment: + если он в динамике по умолчанию, чтобы включить port security надо руками назначить в доступ например...а вот отключаться должен спокойно no switchport port-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте на порту выполнить:

```
no switchport port-security maximum
no switchport port-security mac-address sticky
no switchport port-security
```

Подробнее здесь: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/25ew/configuration/guide/conf/port_sec.html